# How to find bottom section of WP page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm a WP noob and am having trouble locating something in a wp site I inherited. I'm logged into the wp admin for my site and found the home page titled "Home". I know I've got the right page because the content matches the home page on the website. But when I view the html for Home, it's just a table. Yet there is a bunch of content below that table on the home page, maybe a footer or something, and I cannot find the page where that lower content lives. It's definitely not in the "Home" page, as I'm editing it.

Nothing in the list of pages says footer or anything similar. Is there some easy way to locate the lower content so I can edit it?

Comment: It could be a couple of places. Most likely it's either under Appearance -> Widgets in one or more "Footer Widget" areas, or it's in Appearance->Customize. If it isn't in one of those two places, it may be hard coded into the theme's `footer.php`, or in the settings page for a plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find *some* of what I'm looking for, but not all of it. I have looked everywhere.